# How to assign return value outside method it was made

Tags: c#, class, methods

i'm trying to get back value from "piston_code" but i can't figure out how to assign return value out of method "piston_code"

```
class pistons
    {
       public static void piston_code() {
           Random head = new Random();
           int beta = head.Next(100, 999);
           Console.WriteLine("piston serial number " + beta);
      }
```

i think it should look something like this:

```
class pistons
    {
       public static int piston_code() {
           Random head = new Random();
           int beta = head.Next(100, 999);
           Console.WriteLine("piston serial number " + beta);
           return beta; //after that how i can access returned value?
                       // how to assign it to other variable out of "piston_code"?
      }
```

Comment: You need to call your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the result of your function to a variable:

```
int result = pistons.piston_code();
```

The result being that the variable *result* now contains the return value.

Comment: Thanks that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call your method and it already return the int value you want:

```
int beta = pistons.piston_code();
```

Comment: You want to call that from some other function, possibly in another class

Comment: Hey Ashkan, you and I are very much in sync at the minute!!

Comment: yes i want to call it from other class who has Main method